# Attaching listener to element by class in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular (4+) app that uses the https://fullcalendar.io/ library to show a calendar with various events. I'm using the [ap-angular2-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ap-angular2-fullcalendar) as a wrapper for that as well and it can be referenced via the `CalendarComponent`. However, this question isn't necessarily particular to this exact library.

I'd like to trigger something when the mouse goes over the day headings of the various dates. Those elements have the class of `.fc-day-header`, so I'd like to bind to the mouseover and mouseout events on all elements having that class. Also, the calendar takes a while to instantiate, so these elements aren't a part of the DOM until ~200ms after the parent component is created.

The following works, but I feel like I'm not utilizing what's available in Angular correctly. The `setupHeadings()` method is used to add the event listeners (this is simplified to the essential parts):

```
export class Appointments Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  // Access ap2-fullcalendar
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;
  calendarHeaders: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.viewChanged();
  }

  /**
  * It usually takes a few milliseconds to initilize myCalendar, so viewChanged checks first to see
  * if it's available, otherwise it waits 100ms before trying again.
  */
  viewChanged() {
    const viewInformation = this.myCalendar && this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('getView');
    if (viewInformation) {
      this.setApointments();
      this.setupHeadings();
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => this.viewChanged(), 100);
  }

  setupHeadings() {
    const rawCalendarElement = (this.myCalendar['element'] as ElementRef).nativeElement;
    this.calendarHeaders = rawCalendarElement.querySelectorAll('.fc-day-header');
    this.calendarHeaders.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => this.handleDayMouseover(el), false);
      el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => this.handleDayMouseOut(), false);
    });
  }
}
```

I would think that I could create a directive with a class selector to accomplish the same thing, but the following doesn't get run. It is added as a declaration in the parent module and inspired by Natenel Basel's article about [using directives to enhance components when one doesn't have direct access](https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-selectors-in-angular-cd6947ce3bfd):

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '.fc-day-header',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave()'
  }
})
export class DayHoverDirective {

  constructor() {
    console.log('Started');
  }

  onMouseEnter(){
    console.log('Enter');
  }

  onMouseLeave(){
    console.log('Leave');
  }
}
```

However, none of the `console.log()` statements get run (including the constructor). Is that because the fullcalendar component isn't available at the start? Is there something I could/should do to trigger angular to search for `.fc-day-header` after the fullcalendar component is available?

Comment: Just curious: in the first line of `setupHeadings()`, what does `cal` refer to? It's neither an argument, nor declared within the function.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Whoops...I cut out some earlier code that referenced this.myCalendar and assigned it to cal when I tried to shorten up the examples. I've fixed that in the sample code.

Comment: So in https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector, I noticed the line "Angular only allows directives to trigger on CSS selectors that do not cross element boundaries." I'm assuming this is why the directive route doesn't work for me...but I'm still curious if there's a cleaner or more angular-like way to accomplish this.

Comment: Unsure what it means for a selector to "cross element boundaries": does it mean there can be no contained child element?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I'm still trying to figure that out...I'm guessing that since the calendar is a separate module, that's why my directive isn't reaching into that module(?). I would think that this would be a good way to modify modules you don't control...even if I had to specify the directive itself to be applied...something like `@ViewChild(OutsideModule).applyDirective(DayHoverDirective)` (understanding that you don't use `@ViewChild` exactly this way, but that's the gist of it). As I mentioned, the top code works, but I've got to imagine there's a better way.

Comment: Do you declare the directive within the module whose template has the calendar? Unless the Directive is declared in the current module (or imported from another Module that exports it) angular won't recognize it

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes...it's in the module for that template. If I stick a `<div class="fc-day-header">Hover Test</div>` in there, the directive runs, including the mouseovers, so I know the directive works within my template, it just isn't able to pierce into the `<angular2-fullcalendar></angular2-fullcalendar>` component inside that same template.